# Overlay div over an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to overlay a DIV on an image. I am doing this using mouseenter and mouseleave events. I am using Knockout for my data binding.

```
<ul class="gallery" data-bind="foreach: images">
        <li>
            <img data-bind="attr: {src:tUrl},event: {mouseenter: $parent.showOverlay, mouseleave: $parent.hideOverlay}" />
        </li>
</ul>

<div class="list-overlay overlay">
    <img src="/Content/images/play.png" /> Watch
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
showOverlay: function (data, event) {
        var position = $(event.currentTarget).position();
        var height = $(event.currentTarget).innerHeight();
        var width = $(event.currentTarget).innerWidth();

        $(".list-overlay").css("top", parseInt(position.top) + parseInt(height) - 40);
        $(".list-overlay").css("left", position.left);
        $(".list-overlay").css("width", width)
        $(".list-overlay").show();

    },
    hideOverlay: function () {
        $(".list-overlay").hide();
    }
```

Above code works fine to show the overlay. If i start moving the mouse on the overlay it starts flickering as it is firing mouseleave and then mouseenter again and again. I tried using mouseleave and mouseout also but the behavior is same.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to bind mouseleave to the overlay. And at start hideOverlay() check if the pointer is entering the overlay (from the image) or the image (from the overlay), if it is then stop the function by returning, to check that you can use event.relatedTarget

Comment: But I have to hide the overlay when the mouse move out of the image without coming to overlay at all. My overlay does not occupy full image.